# How to keep Virtualizing when style ControlTemplate of ListBox?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, scrollviewer, virtualizingstackpanel, itemspresenter

I read that when styling incorrectly, `ListBox` will lose its virtualization. As [notacat's answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840383/windows-phone-style-make-listbox-s-virtualizing-disabled-how-to-recover-virt), his solution is OK.

I realize that **whenever I put ItemsPresenter in another container**, such as `Grid`, `Border`, ...

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" 
                                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                  Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding MyText}" />
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
</ControlTemplate>
```

`ListBox` will lose its virtualization right away. But I do want to place a `TextBlock` before `ItemsPresenter`, and **ScrollViewer** only accepts 1 child element.

How to deal with this ?

**UPDATE**: 
I see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770892/adding-a-header-to-a-listboxs-scrollviewer-and-keeping-the-virtualizingstackpan?rq=1), which *Derek Lakin* does is to place that `TextBlock` to the `ScrollViewer` template, but how can place that `TextBlock` in `ScrollContentPresenter` ?

**P/S**: I do set `VirtualizingStackPanel` as `ItemsPanel` for my `ListBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating an itemtemplate for a listbox, but it is important for the ItemPresenter to be the direct child of the scrollviewer. 
Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242.aspx for more information on how to template the listbox. I also found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084.aspx) really helpfull.

If the itempresenter can not be direct child, you must give the ItemsPresenter the name, ItemsPresenter.

Comment: you're right. I follow the article you point, but when I set **<ItemsPresenter Name="ItemsPresenter" />** but it doesnot work

Comment: yes, here is the XAML http://pastebin.com/6BSfeyqc and here is the code http://pastebin.com/yxwcFbGX

Comment: Your advice about naming the ItemsPresenter may not have helped the poster, but helped it me, so thank you, thank you!!! 
Before naming, I could not get virtualizing an ItemsControl to work correctly, even though my ControlTemplate is the very basic <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"><ItemsPresenter /></ScrollViewer> format. After naming the ItemsPresenter, it worked like a charm!